# Byte to string for hash function?

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, rest, hash

How can I convert passwordHash to string?

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt());
        student.Password = passwordHash; //this line?
        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

If I try:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt());
        student.Password = Convert.ToString(passwordHash); //this line?
        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

When I GET my Student collection the password field will say System.Byte[] where as I want to get the hashed/salted password back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Convert.ToBase64String Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx):

```
student.Password = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
```

Answer (score 2):

**A sequence of bytes can be represented as a string in infinite ways** so there is no a single valid answer to your question.

The solution already provided of using Convert.ToBase64String() is valid but not the only one you can use.

If you look at the documentation of [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash method on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) 
 the array of bytes is converted in a hexadecimal representation using a code like this:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordHash.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(passwordHash[i].ToString("x2"));
        student.Password = sb.ToString();
```

This is just only an another example.

Answer (score -3):

```
student.Password = Encoding.GetString(passwordHash);
```

This converts a byte array to a string. 
A quick Google search will tell you everything you need to know about manipulating byte arrays, etc...

Comment: All strings can be encoded to a sequence of bytes, but not all sequences of bytes can be decoded to a string.

Comment: dtb: You're correct, but a string IS a sequence of bytes (North America, anyway.) Therefor, depending on the context, this solution does work. If someone doesn't get the desired outcome, it's not because I was wrong, but rather, their design or their question was.